# Why can't I update Adobe Creative Suite?

Tags: windows-8, adobe-creative-suite

I am attempting to check for updates using the Adobe Application Manager on Windows 8 and I get this error:

> The update server is not responding. The server might be offline temporarily, or the Internet or firewall settings may be incorrect.

I have seen this error before on Windows 7 and remembered that I needed to disable the Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter. I navigated to the correct place but the Miniport Adapter was not there. After a bit of searching across several forums I saw a recommendation to change `<logLevel>2</logLevel>`  to `<logLevel>10</logLevel>`. I attempted that and again it still did not work. I have also tried disabling my anti-virus protection and disabling Windows Firewall. Neither worked.

I am not sure what else to try or do at this point.

Are there any other recommendations to solve this issue?

*Notes:*

- I am running Windows 8 Pro using the Creative Cloud Version of CS6.
- I check for updates by choosing `Help` > `Updates` from within any Adobe Application
- This issue was not present in Windows 7 before I upgraded to Windows 8

I originally posted this question on the [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1104227) and received no help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[User `Kipedias` on the Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4903206#4923341) found a solution:

> ~For Windows 8~
>
> 1) Under Control Panel, navigate to the top right search bar and type in "device manager"
>
> 2) Click on "Device manager" after the search
>
> You should see a tree-like map of your devices in the new window
>
> 3) Navigate: view>show hidden devices
>
> 4) Under "Network adapters", right click on the "Microsoft Wi-fi Direct Virtual Adapter" and select disable.
>
> 5) Run updates for your Adobe software on your Windows 8 machine and VOILA!!

---

*Original Answer*

There appears to be an issue with the Adobe Application Manager.

After having an Adobe Connect session with a support person the problem was resolved by replacing the current Adobe Application Manager files with new ones (which had been changed to correct the problem). I was told that Adobe would be releasing an update "shortly."

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem, the only workaroung that worked for me was connecting an ethernet cable.

Windows 8 really does not show miniports on device management and does not allow you to disable them from command prompt, it's a kernel feature for now.

Adone needs to update his Application Manager asap to solve it.